# Create table from many tables with specific data

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

We have oracle11g.

I need to write stored procedure (or may be another solution like creating view) that will truncute old table and insert new updated data.

We have many tables in database with name %table_name%+number_prefix.

For example: `Country_1`, `Country_2`.

Here is data from this tables:

```
id     code     country
103858 834      TZ
103878 834      UA
103859 800      UG
103860 894      ZM
103861 716      ZW        
103862 24       AO
```

Also we have table `Country_all`, with specific information from all this tables.

If users add new table from web gui new `Country_%prefix%` table, i have to update Country_all table. This table should group by code and put all country in one row (TZ, UA, UG ...):

```
table    code    countries
91    2005202000    ,AD,AL,AQ,AS,AT,
91    2005400000    ,AD,AL,AQ,AS,AT,
91    2005995000    ,AD,AL,AQ,AS,AT,
91    2005997000    ,AD,AL,AQ,AS,AT,
91    2006003100    ,AD,AL,AQ,AS,AT,
```

Here 91 means that this data from table `Country_91`

I use this to get prefix from table:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table COUNTRY_ALL';
FOR r IN (SELECT regexp_replace(table_name,'(.*)_', '\1') ADD_NUM
FROM all_tables
WHERE upper(table_name)
LIKE ('COUNTRY_%'))
```

But when i try to use `r.ADD_NUM` i have trouble.

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_ALL
SELECT r.ADD_NUM, code, listagg(code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) AS GI_COUNTRIES
FROM 'COUNTRY_' || r.ADD_NUM
GROUP BY code;
```

I also try to declare some variable and assign `COUNTRY_ || r.ADD_NUM` to the variable, but it also don't want to query from variable.

**UPDATE**

Finally i did it yesterday!

I did it in two ways. The **first** one is exactly what i was asking:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table Countries_ALL';
  FOR r IN (SELECT regexp_replace(table_name,'_(.*)', '\1') ADD_NUM
        FROM all_tables
        WHERE upper(table_name)
        LIKE ('COUNTRY_%')
        AND owner='owner_name')
  loop


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'INSERT COUNTRIES_ALL
      SELECT '|| r.ADD_NUM ||' as ADD_NUM, code, listagg(countries, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY countries) AS COUNTRIES
      FROM COUNTRY_' || r.ADD_NUM || '
      GROUP by code;         
  END loop;
END;
```

The **second** one is better. I create 2 temporary tables: `CURRENT` and `FOR_UPDATING`.

To fill `CURRENT`:

```
INSERT INTO CURRENT
SELECT DISTINCT ADD_NUM FROM COUNTRIES_ALL;
```

And procedure that will update only not existing table, unlike previous one:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
execute IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE table for_updating';

  INSERT INTO for_updating
    SELECT regexp_replace(table_name,'_(.*)', '\5 ') as ADD_NUM
        FROM all_tables
         WHERE owner='owner_name'
         AND table_name LIKE 'COUNTRY_%';

for num in (
SELECT b.add_num FROM CURRENT A
RIGHT JOIN for_updating b
ON A.add_num=b.add_num
WHERE A.add_num IS NULL) 
loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'INSERT INTO COUNTRIES_ALL
          SELECT '||num.add_num||' as ADD_NUM, code, listagg(countries, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY countries) AS GI_COUNTRIES
          FROM COUNTRY_' || num.ADD_NUM || '
          GROUP by code';

end loop;

END;
```

In this procedure i compare what tables i already have in `COUNTRIES_ALL` and what i have in all_tables. Then all new tables will be inserted.

Thanks to Przemyslaw Kruglej for his patience!

Comment: Remove the `r.` before the ADD_NUM - does that help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I think the problem is in listagg(code, '','')

Comment: Can you run this query as a standalone query (without the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE)? Does it work then?

Comment: Yes it works without EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, it said anonymous block completed, also i have to remove one pair of single quotes '','' -> ','

Comment: Ah.. remove the semicolon just before the closing apostrophe so  it is like this: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'INSERT INTO COUNTRY_ALL
    SELECT r.ADD_NUM, code, listagg(code, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) AS GI_COUNTRIES
      FROM COUNTRY_' || tab_number ||
    ' GROUP BY code';`

Comment: You deleted the wrong semicolon. Delete the one INSIDE the apostrophes, not the one at the end :) Check code in my previous comment, or the code in my post below which I edited.

Comment: I did it yesterday, question is updated. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run a query with dynamic name of the table.

You have to either generate a query for each of the tables, use dbms_sql package or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Do you know the number of the table you are supposed to work on? If so, you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'INSERT INTO COUNTRY_ALL
    SELECT r.ADD_NUM, code, listagg(code, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) AS GI_COUNTRIES
      FROM COUNTRY_' || tab_number ||
    ' GROUP BY code';
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually i know number of the new table. But i want this thing to be something automatically.

Comment: Ok, but you can use what I wrote in my post if you will be able to somehow dynamically obtain the number of the table you have to work with. Or am I missing something? What stops you right now from making this work automatically?

Comment: For example users add a few new tables. Now i should manually run procedure with obtained numbers. But I want procedure that will automatically run onсe a day. What if i (select distinct add_num from country_all) and obtain numbers that i already have. Then using previuos code obtain all numbers. How can i compare them to get only new one? It is possible using only pl/sql?

Comment: So you'd like to know which tables were created today - you could store the number of the last table that was created the day before in some configuration table, and then run your job which will get new numbers (new equal those that are greater than the remembered value) and perform EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on those tables. Then, when you finish, update the number of the last table to be equal to the number of the last table you updated during this day's job. You could, also, check the DDL time of the tables you are working with, but I wouldn't recommend this approach (1st approach is better).